# R print a units number with the respective unit

Tags: r, units-of-measurement

I have a script using number parameters with units. When printing messages to the log/user, I want the print to add the respective unit.
I expected R to be smart enough to do so when doing:

```
library(units)

min_size = set_units(1200, "m^2")
print(paste0("Must be at least ", min_size))

# Prints: "Must be at least 1200"
# I want: "Must be at least 1200 m^2")

# ideally without explicitly adding " m^2", to avoid code inconsistency when changing units
print(paste0("Must be at least ", min_size, " m^2"))
```

Comment: You should specify where `set_units` comes from, obviously it is that package that is not smart enough.

Comment: If you understand S3 classes, you know why it can't be "smart enough".

Comment: @jay.sf thanks for the suggestion, I added the package (units). Your comment suggests that there is a package that prints the unit by default... if that is the case, you may want to add it as an (alternative) answer :)

Comment: @Honeybear Thanks for adding, I'd use `sprintf("Must be at least %s %s", min_size, units(min_size))` in this case.

Comment: @Roland Could you explain what you mean by “can’t be”? Obviously the package could trivially provide a suitable implementation for the `as.character.units` method. In fact, the package *does* provide methods for `as.character`. I have no idea why the package authors decided not to append the unit (I am assuming there’s a good reason since the authors are knowledgeable — then again, there are some trivial code quality issues that I could find at a cursory look!) but it’s not a technical limitation of the S3 system.

Comment: You are right, it is feasible. But having `as.character` append a unit is not a choice I would make. `format` exists for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of workarounds:  printing the units explicitly, or using `format()` to append them automatically.

I'll try to answer the question of why your original attempt (relying on `paste0()` to do the formatting) didn't work.

`paste0()` converts objects to character strings using `as.character()`.  In general, `as.character()` isn't the method you should use for a nice display.  For example, `as.character(pi)` gives `"3.14159265358979"`, ignoring the user's `options("digits")` setting.  When you want things displayed in a nice user-friendly way, use `format()` to do the conversion.  For example, `format(pi)` gives `"3.141593"`.

So why doesn't `paste0()` use `format()`?  Because `format()` loses a lot of information when it rounds.  You can't get it back from the string produced.  On the other hand, `as.character()` loses less. (It does lose some info; `as.numeric(as.character(pi))` is not equal to `pi`, and `as.character(min_size)` uses the default method, so it loses the unit information.)

I hope this helps to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use `units(min_size)` to get a printable representation of the unit.

```
print(paste0("Must be at least ", min_size, " ", units(min_size)))
```

Comment: You can use `format` like this: `units_options(group = c("", "")); print(paste0("Must be at least ", format(min_size)))`.